# Plot Audio DAta

Tags: plotting, sound, signal-processing

I am a beginner in mathematica.

Currently i am working on audio file my problem is when i extract audio information using BinaryReadList and try to plot it works with mono wav file but cannot get with sterio file. Can anyone help me where i went wrong or how i can get it right. Here a1.wav is a single(mono) channel audio while bird.wav is dual(sterio) channel.

Mono:
[image]

Stereo:
[image]

Comment: Crossposted [here](https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/1738397).

Comment: Try `{left, right} = Import["filename", "Sound"][[1, 1]];`

Comment: i want to plot only after the sterio wav file is converted to its correspongding integers.